# return 0 is count for particular condition is NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select DATE(feed_date) as date, 
       IFNULL(COUNT(id),0) as count 
from table 
where id = 8671 
group by DATE(feed_date);
```

I want "0" as an entry in my result when there is no entry for `id` in a particular date.

Comment: Do you need all dates in a particular range?

Comment: yes all dates in a particular date range @wietze314

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select DATE(feed_date) as fdate, 
       SUM(id = 8671) as count 
from table 
group by fdate
```

Comment: Please clarify what you need. I think my answer is correct. You could add example data to your question.

Comment: Just a small warning: If a particular date is not present in the table, it will not appear as a result in the query.